# boost::asio write hangs for large sizes

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I am using boost::asio to implement a tcp server and client. 
I am using the write and read functions when the size of the file is large the write hangs and does not complete.

This is the function which reads

```
int send_request(std::string &ep_ip, int ep_port, std::string &message, std::string &response) {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(ep_ip), ep_port);
    try {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
        boost::system::error_code error;
        socket.connect(ep);
        std::vector<char> buf(BUF_SIZE);
        // buf = new std::vector<char>(BUF_SIZE);
        std::copy(message.begin(), message.end(), buf.begin());
        boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);
        // int bytes_read = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf) , error );
        int bytes_read = boost::asio::read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);
        std::copy(buf.begin(), buf.begin() + bytes_read, std::back_inserter(response));
        socket.close();
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        // std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This is the function which writes

```
void listen(int port_no, std::string &filename) {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    std::string result = "";
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port_no));
    while (1) {
        tcp::socket socket(io_service);
        std::vector<char> buf(BUF_SIZE);
        boost::system::error_code ignored_error, error;
        acceptor.accept(socket);
        int req_bytes_read = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);
        std::string request;
        std::copy(buf.begin(), buf.begin() + req_bytes_read, std::back_inserter(request));
        request = clean_string(request);
        if (error) {
            std::cout << "[ERROR] Unable to process the request. CODE  " << error << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Received the message: " << request << std::endl;
            // This where we do some processing of the request, perhaps call grep.
            std::string PATH = "$HOME/" + filename;
            result = "";
            grep_impl(request, PATH, result);
            // result = grep(request , PATH);
        }
        std::cout << "Size of result is " << result.size() << std::endl;
        boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(result), ignored_error);
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The size of _what_ file? You don't read any file

Comment: so grep_impl puts a large string in result . 38mb to be precise

Comment: I've updated my answer (why didn't you take the sample code and modify it to show the problem?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so grep_impl puts a large string in result . 38mb to be precise – Rahul Mahadev 18 hours ago

So, in response to that comment: you only ever read `BUF_SIZE` characters.

*(Note that this still would not lead to hanging writes, because the write operation will simply stop as the connection gets reset by the peer, you have an explicit `socket.close()` in the `send_request` client).*

To read a larger response (I'm assuming 38mb is larger) you *need* a loop.

```
while (!error) {
    int bytes_read = ba::read(socket, ba::buffer(buf), error);
    std::copy(buf.begin(), buf.begin() + bytes_read, std::back_inserter(response));
    if (bytes_read == 0)
        break;
}
```

You can expect the error to usually become `eof` when the server stops transmission.

1. You send all the bytes in `buf`, even those not filled. I'm not sure this is on purpose, but at least it's corrupting the output.

   Oh. Maybe it's `clean_string` that does this, but why not simply send only the request?

Here's a self-contained demonstration transferring 38mb of data using a 1k buffer:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/745cb443de1d462f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

static constexpr size_t BUF_SIZE = 1024u;

namespace ba = boost::asio;
using ba::ip::tcp;

int send_request(std::string const& ep_ip, int ep_port, std::string const& message, std::string &response) {
    ba::io_service io_service;
    tcp::endpoint ep(ba::ip::address::from_string(ep_ip), ep_port);
    try {
        tcp::socket socket(io_service);
        boost::system::error_code error;
        socket.connect(ep);
        std::vector<char> buf(BUF_SIZE);
        std::copy(message.begin(), message.end(), buf.begin());

        ba::write(socket, ba::buffer(buf), error);

        // int bytes_read = socket.read_some(ba::buffer(buf) , error );

        while (!error) {
            int bytes_read = ba::read(socket, ba::buffer(buf), error);
            std::copy(buf.begin(), buf.begin() + bytes_read, std::back_inserter(response));
            if (bytes_read == 0)
                break;
        }

        socket.close();
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        // std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

std::string clean_string(std::string const& s) { 
    return s.c_str(); // Cut from NUL
}

void grep_impl(std::string const& /*request*/, std::string const& /*PATH*/, std::string& result) {
    result = std::string(38ul << 20, '*');
}

void listen(int port_no, std::string const& filename) {
    ba::io_service io_service;
    std::string result = "";
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port_no));
    while (1) {
        tcp::socket socket(io_service);
        std::vector<char> buf(BUF_SIZE);
        boost::system::error_code ignored_error, error;
        acceptor.accept(socket);
        int req_bytes_read = socket.read_some(ba::buffer(buf), error);
        std::string request;
        std::copy(buf.begin(), buf.begin() + req_bytes_read, std::back_inserter(request));

        request = clean_string(request);
        if (error) {
            std::cout << "[ERROR] Unable to process the request. CODE  " << error << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Received the message: " << request << std::endl;
            // This where we do some processing of the request, perhaps call grep.
            std::string PATH = "$HOME/" + filename;
            result = "";
            grep_impl(request, PATH, result);
            // result = grep(request , PATH);
        }
        std::cout << "Size of result is " << result.size() << std::endl;
        ba::write(socket, ba::buffer(result), ignored_error);
        socket.close();
        break;
    }
}

#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::thread_group tg;
    tg.create_thread([]{ listen(6767, "test.cpp"); });
    tg.create_thread([]{ 
            boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));
            std::string response;
            send_request("127.0.0.1", 6767, "TEST", response);

            std::cout << "send_request returned " << response.size() << " bytes";
        });

    tg.join_all();
}
```

Prints

```
Received the message: TEST
Size of result is 39845888
send_request returned 39845888 bytes
```